# Why does Chainlink VRFv2 not support L2 rollup chain like arbitrum or optimism?

Tags: chainlink, rollups, chainlink-vrf

All the popular L2 rollup chains are not listed in the supported networks per doc: https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/direct-funding/supported-networks/.

Meanwhile, Aribitrum and Optimism do have integrations with DataFeeds. Links:

1. https://www.chainlinkecosystem.com/ecosystem/arbitrum
2. https://www.chainlinkecosystem.com/ecosystem/optimism

Comment: The question is not "Why", but "When".
This is probably on the roadmap :)

Comment: k, question answered